# What is the difference between normal and shortform opcodes in CIL?

Tags: cil

I am going through various opcodes in CIL and I find a lot of similar looking codes like 
Beq,Beq_S
Bge,Bge_S
Bgt,Bgt_S
Br,Br_S

Where S is supposedly "short form". What does that mean??

Comment: I understand that Short refers to the operand size where a _s instruction takes a singe byte operand. But what is the reason for having two such instructions?? please provide a situation where one is preferred over the other.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The short forms of the instructions take up less space (that is, the binary encoding of the CIL instructions are themselves shorter, so your assembly will take up less space on disk or in memory).  Therefore, they would typically be preferred when applicable.  However, the tradeoff is that they have limited ranges compared to the full forms of the instructions (e.g. branch target offsets must fit within bytes instead of ints).